# How to save the password for the next commands in the shell script?

Tags: shell-script, password, ansible

When my script starts, the shell asks me for the password for the module `apt-get`, and then again for `ansible`, because it has the option `--ask-get-pass`.

How do I enter the password only once for this script?

```bsh
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install -y ansible &&

ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass playbook.yml
```

Comment: Do you feel confident enough to store it as a variable that is asked for at the beginning of the script via `read`?

Comment: Good question. I run the script on my desktop. In this case (read), the password will be stored in the shell history?

Comment: But you don't get asked for the password multiple times for the three `apt-get` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` command works in my case:

```
read -s -p "SUDO Password: " pass

echo "$pass" | sudo -S apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install -y ansible &&

ansible-playbook --extra-vars "ansible_become_pass=$pass" playbook.yml
```

@Cometsong thanks for clue